# two groups of sample

Tags: nonparametric

hi there please tell me what it can be called when two sample groups are used in a research for example employees and managers. Moreover, whether there is any benefit of using two categories of sample. thanks

Comment: 'Two sample groups' that is likely to be called 'a comparison' but does not have to, depending on context. As it stands, I don't understand the question. Please try to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stratification. You have two strata, employees and managers.

There are benefits. Suppose, for example, you want the same accuracy level (e.g. plus or minus 5%) for the employee estimates and the manager estimates.  Then you will want approximately the same sample size for both strata.  But if there are 5000 employees and 500 managers, you will want to take a different fraction in each strata.

Second, you will likely want to separate the strata for analysis comparing the two groups.